# How can I select data from rows and display it as columns using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, csv

I have a table with data in it as such:

```
Cars:
id | name
----------
1  | Buick
2  | Honda
3  | Toyota
```

What I would like to do in a stored procedure is get a result like this:

```
Temp Table:
Buick | Honda | Toyota
----------------------
```

I realize it has no values, but I just want to get this part first.

I am guessing this would involve some sort of temporary table.

Using MS SQL 2005.

Comment: so what you are trying to do is get the names of the different cars and make them into column names themselve?

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)?

Here's a (slightly contrived) example based on the MSDN example modified for your example:

```
SELECT 'Count' AS Header,
    [Toyota], [Buick], [Honda]
FROM (SELECT id, Name FROM Cars) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT( COUNT(ID) FOR Name IN ([Toyota], [Buick], [Honda])) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: This works if you only have 3 columns for 3 rows. 
For a true row to column conversion, you only have dynamic SQL or do it in client code

Answer (score 0):

You want string concatenation, or PIVOT as above suggested?
question was ambiguous, you want row values to turn into columns (PIVOT), or output?

just read this like 1 hour ago on [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/bf43ff28-1110-4f98-a1b6-3522ad9532f4)
Use FOR XML

```
SELECT 
STUFF(
(
SELECT ' ' + name
FROM @table
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') as concatenated_string
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a temporary table, then create a cursor for a selection from the Cars table and for each row dynamically create and execute an SQL query that adds a field to the temporary table.

But why are you trying to do something like this? You are mixing data with meta data, and that is rarely a good idea. The code for populating the temporary table with data will be even worse than the code for creating it.

I think that you are too much focused on getting the output from the stored procedure to look like how you are going to display it. Instead try to figure out how the data should be arranged to be convenient to work with.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you (whoever) don't leave a comment explaining why, it's pointless.